# Get calling UserID from Custom Workflow in Dynamics CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to get the UserID of the current user from whom the Workflow was executed in Dynamics CRM 4.

I did it using the

```
IWorkflowContext.UserID
```

but it gets the ID of the Workflow Owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve this information unless a user explicitly ran the workflow "on demand." If the workflow was triggered via a crm action (such as create of a record) it will run under the context of the workflow owner.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/06/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-iworkflowcontext-interface.aspx) from a member of the crm support team:

> UserId: If the workflow was executed on demand, this will be the ID of the user who executed the workflow. If the workflow was executed due to a message executing, then it will be the ID of the workflow owner.